# sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full (E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)

Tags: ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i installed ros-indigo in Ubuntu 14.04. i removed ros-indigo. i decide reinstall this agian , but when run this command (`sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full`) in terminal, this error is created:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282399/sudo-apt-get-install-ros-indigo-desktop-full-(e:-unable-to-correct-problems,-you-have-held-broken-packages.)/) by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-02-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-11**:
One thing to check: did you a any point install a version of Gazebo newer than `2` (ie: `gazebo7` fi)? If so, remove it. Then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was having this problem with my installation earlier today although I was installing kinetic. I got around this by first installing aptitude

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

then using aptitude to install ros

```
sudo aptitude install ros-<package>-desktop-full
```

---

Originally posted by [nickd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3862/nickd/) with karma: 92 on 2018-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on 2018-02-11**:
thanks nickd, my problem is solved!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-01**:
@zahra.kh if this solved your problem then please click the next to the answer to mark the answer as correct.

**Comment by [shahriarMJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/56783/shahriarmj/) on 2020-07-18**:
I had same problem with Installing ROS 2 Eloquent Elusor. I just deleted the `full` tag from the end of  `sudo aptitude install ros-<package>-desktop-full` command.
Hope it will help somebody